# Parsing raw data received from bluetooth HDP device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to read data from an Omron 708-BT Blood Pressure Monitor which is certified by the continua health alliance. I am following this example [of a Bluetooth HDP App](https://github.com/james11/BluetoothHDPActivity/tree/3f64bf701fbbfa51cbc3472d5826a7b1c6957ad4/src/com/larc/bluetooth/health). I am managing to connect to the device and retrieve data in byte format but cannot parse the data to get the values needed. I am trying to follow the IEEE Blood Pressure specification specified on page 19 of this [PDF](http://www.telemedicina.ufsc.br/padroes/images/11073_10407_2008.pdf).

Here is the code which has been added to the example code linked above.

```
//Variables in the class
private int count;
private byte[] invoke = {0x00, 0x00};
private class ReadThread extends Thread {
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mFd;

    public ReadThread(ParcelFileDescriptor fd) {
        super();
        mFd = fd;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFd.getFileDescriptor());
        final byte data[] = new byte[300];
        try {
            while(fis.read(data) > -1) {
                // At this point, the application can pass the raw data to a parser that
                // has implemented the IEEE 11073-xxxxx specifications.  Instead, this sample
                // simply indicates that some data has been received
                Log.e("Test", data.toString()); 

                 if (data[0] != (byte) 0x00)
                 {
                     String test = byte2hex(data);
                     Log.i(TAG, test);
                     if(data[0] == (byte) 0xE2){
                         Log.i(TAG, "E2");
                         count = 1;
                         
                         (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                         try {
                             sleep(100);
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         Log.i(TAG, "Seconds Write Thread");
                         count = 2;
                         (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                     }
                     else if (data[0] == (byte)0xE7){
                         Log.i(TAG, "E7");
                         
                         count = 3; 
                         //set invoke id so get correct response
                         invoke = new byte[] { data[6], data[7] };
                         (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();     
                         //parse data!!
                         int number_of_data_packets = data[25];
                         int packet_start = 30;
                         final int SYS_DIA_MAP_DATA = 1;
                         final int PULSE_DATA = 2;
                         final int ERROR_CODE_DATA = 3;

                         for (int i = 0; i < number_of_data_packets; i++){
                                Log.e("TEST", Integer.toString(i));
                               int obj_handle = data[packet_start+1];
                               switch (obj_handle)
                               {
                               case SYS_DIA_MAP_DATA:
                                   int sys = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+9]);
                                   int dia = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+11]);
                                   int map = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+13]);
                                   //create team string... 9+13~9+20   
                                   Log.e("RESULT", "sys is "+ sys);
                                   sendMessage(RECEIVED_SYS, sys);
                                   Log.e("RESULT", "dia is "+ dia);
                                   sendMessage(RECEIVED_DIA, dia);
                                   Log.e("RESULT", "map is "+ map);

                                   break;
                               case PULSE_DATA:
                                   //parse
                                   int pulse = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+5]);
                                   Log.e("RESULT", "pulse is " + pulse);
                                   sendMessage(RECEIVED_PUL, pulse);
                                   break;
                               case ERROR_CODE_DATA:
                                   //need more signal
                                   break;
                               }
                               packet_start += 1;//4 + data[packet_start+3];   //4 = ignore beginning four bytes
                           }  
                     }
                     else if (data[0] == (byte) 0xE4)
                     {
                   
                         count = 4;
                         (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                     }
                     //zero out the data
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                         data[i] = (byte) 0x00;
                     }
                 }
                 sendMessage(STATUS_READ_DATA, 0);
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {}
        if (mFd != null) {
            try {
                mFd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* Do nothing. */ }
        }
        sendMessage(STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE, 0);
    }
}

private class WriteThread extends Thread {
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mFd;

    public WriteThread(ParcelFileDescriptor fd) {
        super();
        mFd = fd;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mFd.getFileDescriptor());
        final byte data_AR[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x2C, 
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x79,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x26,
                                                    (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08,  //bt add for phone, can be automate in the future
                                                    (byte) 0x3C, (byte) 0x5A, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0xFF, 
                                                    (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0xE3,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
        final byte data_DR[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x12,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10,
                                                    (byte) invoke[0], (byte) invoke[1],
                                                    (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0A,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x1D,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

        final byte get_MDS[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0E,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0C,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x24,
                                                    (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

        final byte data_RR[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE5, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

        final byte data_RRQ[] = new byte[] {        (byte) 0xE4, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

        final byte data_ABORT[] = new byte[] {      (byte) 0xE6, (byte) 0x00,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02,
                                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(count));
            if (count == 1)
            {
                fos.write(data_AR);
                Log.i(TAG, "Association Responded!");
            }  
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                fos.write(get_MDS);
                Log.i(TAG, "Get MDS object attributes!");
            }
            else if (count == 3) 
            {
                fos.write(data_DR);
                Log.i(TAG, "Data Responsed!");
            }
            else if (count == 4)
            {
                fos.write(data_RR);
                Log.i(TAG, "Data Released!");
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {}
    }
```

The hex representation of the data is the following. I believe this data hold the values from the blood pressure values but may be wrong. The only reason I believe this is because in the PDF linked above it days the data will start with the hex value e7.

> 03-23 20:14:44.186: I/BluetoothHDPService(23652):
> e70000da00d80024020300d20000000a00cc0928002000104f4d524f4e204845414c544843415245000c48454d2d373038312d4954000984000a0008002209225835c3280a5a000800010004100700010a4400024000092d00360002003200010001001653455249414c5f4e554d4245523a200000000000004100050001001046575f5245564953494f4e3a203130310914000400005dc00a4b0016000200120201000801000001000200070202000200000a450010c0101f00ffffffff00640000000000000a550008000100040a620006098700082010010100013600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: You are already parsing the data. So where is the problem?

Comment: @greenapps The parse doesn't work. The hex string I spent isn't in the format I am expecting. So I cannot extract the blood pressure values from it. Everything inside else if (data[0] == (byte)0xE7){ } is probably wrong. Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you wrote that parsing code or did you copy it from the pdf?

Comment: @greenapps I got this code from another example using a different monitor.

Comment: What is a different monitor?

Comment: A different blood pressure monitor. But it uses the same standardized Health Device Profile bluetooth protocol.

Comment: This is one of the few posts I've come across dealing with the Continua standard from a developer's perspective. How did you find working with Continua from a technical perspective? I know the effort has been around for a while, but I haven't seen many developers getting excited about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The main issue I had was that I only took one blood pressure reading then kept pressing upload. This does upload some information about the monitor but doesn't include a blood pressure reading. Once I knew this I had a number of other smaller bugs to solve but nothing too complicated. The code for the final working service is below.

```
public class BluetoothHDPService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothHDPService";

    public static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
    public static final int RESULT_FAIL = -1;

    // Status codes sent back to the UI client.
    // Application registration complete.
    public static final int STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG = 100;
    // Application unregistration complete.
    public static final int STATUS_HEALTH_APP_UNREG = 101;
    // Channel creation complete.
    public static final int STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL = 102;
    // Channel destroy complete.
    public static final int STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL = 103;
    // Reading data from Bluetooth HDP device.
    public static final int STATUS_READ_DATA = 104;
    // Done with reading data.
    public static final int STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE = 105;

    // Message codes received from the UI client.
    // Register client with this service.
    public static final int MSG_REG_CLIENT = 200;
    // Unregister client from this service.
    public static final int MSG_UNREG_CLIENT = 201;
    // Register health application.
    public static final int MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP = 300;
    // Unregister health application.
    public static final int MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP = 301;
    // Connect channel.
    public static final int MSG_CONNECT_CHANNEL = 400;
    // Disconnect channel.
    public static final int MSG_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL = 401;

    public static final int RECEIVED_SYS = 901;

    public static final int RECEIVED_DIA = 902;

    public static final int RECEIVED_PUL = 903;

    private int count;
    private byte[] invoke = {0x00, 0x00};

    private BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration mHealthAppConfig;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothHealth mBluetoothHealth;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private int mChannelId;

    private Messenger mClient;

    // Handles events sent by {@link HealthHDPActivity}.
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                // Register UI client to this service so the client can receive messages.
                case MSG_REG_CLIENT:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Activity client registered");
                    mClient = msg.replyTo;
                    break;
                // Unregister UI client from this service.
                case MSG_UNREG_CLIENT:
                    mClient = null;
                    break;
                // Register health application.
                case MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP:
                    registerApp(msg.arg1);
                    break;
                // Unregister health application.
                case MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP:
                    unregisterApp();
                    break;
                // Connect channel.
                case MSG_CONNECT_CHANNEL:
                    mDevice = (BluetoothDevice) msg.obj;
                    connectChannel();
                    break;
                // Disconnect channel.
                case MSG_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL:
                    mDevice = (BluetoothDevice) msg.obj;
                    disconnectChannel();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

    /**
     * Make sure Bluetooth and health profile are available on the Android device.  Stop service
     * if they are not available.
     */
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.e("TEST", "HDPService Created");

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // Bluetooth adapter isn't available.  The client of the service is supposed to
            // verify that it is available and activate before invoking this service.
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mBluetoothServiceListener,
                BluetoothProfile.HEALTH)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "bluetooth_health_profile_not_available", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BluetoothHDPService is running.");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    };

    // Register health application through the Bluetooth Health API.
    private void registerApp(int dataType) {
        Log.e(TAG, "registerApp()");
        mBluetoothHealth.registerSinkAppConfiguration(TAG, dataType, mHealthCallback);
    }

    // Unregister health application through the Bluetooth Health API.
    private void unregisterApp() {
        Log.e(TAG, "unregisterApp()");
        mBluetoothHealth.unregisterAppConfiguration(mHealthAppConfig);
    }

    // Connect channel through the Bluetooth Health API.
    private void connectChannel() {
        Log.i(TAG, "connectChannel()");
        mBluetoothHealth.connectChannelToSource(mDevice, mHealthAppConfig);
    }

    // Disconnect channel through the Bluetooth Health API.
    private void disconnectChannel() {
        Log.i(TAG, "disconnectChannel()");
        mBluetoothHealth.disconnectChannel(mDevice, mHealthAppConfig, mChannelId);
    }

    // Callbacks to handle connection set up and disconnection clean up.
    private final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mBluetoothServiceListener =
            new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEALTH) {
                mBluetoothHealth = (BluetoothHealth) proxy;
                if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
                    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected to profile: " + profile);
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEALTH) {
                mBluetoothHealth = null;
            }
        }
    };

    private final BluetoothHealthCallback mHealthCallback = new BluetoothHealthCallback() {
        // Callback to handle application registration and unregistration events.  The service
        // passes the status back to the UI client.
        public void onHealthAppConfigurationStatusChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
                int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_FAILURE) {
                mHealthAppConfig = null;
                sendMessage(STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG, RESULT_FAIL);
            } else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                mHealthAppConfig = config;
                sendMessage(STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG, RESULT_OK);
            } else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_FAILURE ||
                    status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                sendMessage(STATUS_HEALTH_APP_UNREG,
                        status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS ?
                        RESULT_OK : RESULT_FAIL);
            }
        }

        // Callback to handle channel connection state changes.
        // Note that the logic of the state machine may need to be modified based on the HDP device.
        // When the HDP device is connected, the received file descriptor is passed to the
        // ReadThread to read the content.
        public void onHealthChannelStateChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
                BluetoothDevice device, int prevState, int newState, ParcelFileDescriptor fd,
                int channelId) {

            Log.e("Read Thread", "Start If Statements");
            Log.e("Read Thread", "prevState: " + prevState);
            Log.e("Read Thread", "newState: " + newState);

            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("prevState\t%d ----------> newState\t%d",
                        prevState, newState));

//            if (prevState != BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED &&
//                    newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {

            if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED &&
                    newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {
                if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {
                    mChannelId = channelId;
                    sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
                    Log.e("Read Thread", "Read  Start 1");
                    (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
                } else {
                    Log.e("Read Thread", "Status Create Channel Fail 1");
                    sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
                }
            } else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING &&
                       newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) {
                sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
                Log.e("Read Thread", "Status Create Channel Fail 2");
            } else if (newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) {
                if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {
                    sendMessage(STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
                    Log.e("Read Thread", "Status Disconnect OK");
                } else {
                    sendMessage(STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
                    Log.e("Read Thread", "Status Disconnect FAIL");
                }
            }else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING && newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {
                if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {
                    mChannelId = channelId;
                    sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
                    Log.e("Read Thread", "Read  Start 2");
                    (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
                } else {
                    sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
                    Log.e("Read Thread", "Status Create Channel Fail 3");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Sends an update message to registered UI client.
    private void sendMessage(int what, int value) {
        if (mClient == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No clients registered.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            mClient.send(Message.obtain(null, what, value, 0));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Unable to reach client.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String byte2hex(byte[] b){
     // String Buffer can be used instead
       String hs = "";
       String stmp = "";

       for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n++){
          stmp = (java.lang.Integer.toHexString(b[n] & 0XFF));

          if (stmp.length() == 1){
             hs = hs + "0" + stmp;
          }
          else{
             hs = hs + stmp;
          }
          if (n < b.length - 1){
             hs = hs + "";
          }
       }

       return hs;
    }

    public static int byteToUnsignedInt(byte b) {
        return 0x00 << 24 | b & 0xff;
    }

    public static int toInt(byte[] bytes) {
          int ret = 0;
          for (int i=0; i<4 && i<bytes.length; i++) {
            ret <<= 8;
            ret |= (int)bytes[i] & 0xFF;
          }
          return ret;
    }

    // Thread to read incoming data received from the HDP device.  This sample application merely
    // reads the raw byte from the incoming file descriptor.  The data should be interpreted using
    // a health manager which implements the IEEE 11073-xxxxx specifications.
    private class ReadThread extends Thread {
        private ParcelFileDescriptor mFd;

        public ReadThread(ParcelFileDescriptor fd) {
            super();
            mFd = fd;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("TEST", "Read Data 1");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFd.getFileDescriptor());
            final byte data[] = new byte[200];
            Log.i(TAG, "Read Data 2");
            try {
                while(fis.read(data) > -1) {
                    // At this point, the application can pass the raw data to a parser that
                    // has implemented the IEEE 11073-xxxxx specifications.  Instead, this sample
                    // simply indicates that some data has been received.

                    Log.i(TAG, "INBOUND");
                    String test = byte2hex(data);
                    Log.i(TAG, test);

                     if (data[0] != (byte) 0x00)
                     {

                         if(data[0] == (byte) 0xE2){
                             Log.i(TAG, "E2 - Association Request");
                             count = 1;

                             (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                             try {
                                 sleep(100);
                             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                             count = 2;
                             (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                         }
                         else if (data[0] == (byte)0xE7){
                             Log.i(TAG, "E7 - Data Given");


                             if(data[3] != (byte)0xda){

                                 invoke[0] = data[6];
                                 invoke[1] = data[7];

                                    Log.i(TAG, "E7 - Reading?");
                                    ByteBuffer sys = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
                                     sys.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                                     sys.put(data[45]);
                                     sys.put(data[46]);
                                     short sysVal = sys.getShort(0);
                                     Log.i(TAG, " Sys - "+sysVal);

                                    ByteBuffer dia = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
                                     dia.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                                     dia.put(data[47]);
                                     dia.put(data[48]);
                                     short diaVal = dia.getShort(0);
                                     Log.i(TAG, " Dia - "+diaVal);

                                     sendMessage(9919, diaVal);
                                     sendMessage(9920, sysVal);



                                   for(int i=0; i<(data.length-2); i++){
                                     ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
                                     bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                                     bb.put(data[i]);
                                     bb.put(data[i+1]);
                                     short shortVal = bb.getShort(0);
                                     Log.i(TAG, i+" Short Val - "+shortVal);

                                 }

                                   count = 3; 
                                   //set invoke id so get correct response 
                                   (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                             }
                             //parse data!!
                         }
                         else if (data[0] == (byte) 0xE4)
                         {
                             //count = 4;
                            // (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();
                         }
                         //zero out the data
                         for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                             data[i] = (byte) 0x00;
                         }
                     }
                     sendMessage(STATUS_READ_DATA, 0);
                }
            } catch(IOException ioe) {}
            if (mFd != null) {
                try {
                    mFd.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { /* Do nothing. */ }
            }
            sendMessage(STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE, 0);
        }
    }

    private class WriteThread extends Thread {
        private ParcelFileDescriptor mFd;

        public WriteThread(ParcelFileDescriptor fd) {
            super();
            mFd = fd;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mFd.getFileDescriptor());
            final byte data_AR[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x2C, 
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x79,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x26,
                                                        (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08,  //bt add for phone, can be automate in the future
                                                        (byte) 0x3C, (byte) 0x5A, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0xFF, 
                                                        (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0xE3,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, 
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
            final byte data_DR[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x12,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x24,
                                                        (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0A,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x1D,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

            final byte get_MDS[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0E,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0C,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x24,
                                                        (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

            final byte data_RR[] = new byte[] {         (byte) 0xE5, (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02,
                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

//            final byte data_RRQ[] = new byte[] {        (byte) 0xE4, (byte) 0x00,
//                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02,
//                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
//
//            final byte data_ABORT[] = new byte[] {      (byte) 0xE6, (byte) 0x00,
//                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02,
//                                                        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(count));
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    fos.write(data_AR);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Association Responded!");
                }  
                else if (count == 2)
                {
                    fos.write(get_MDS);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Get MDS object attributes!");
                }
                else if (count == 3) 
                {
                    fos.write(data_DR);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Responsed!");
                }
                else if (count == 4)
                {
                    fos.write(data_RR);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Released!");
                }
            } catch(IOException ioe) {}
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i am not able to connect to the pulse oximeter device. at the first state it is disconnected -- connecting. again it is connecting -- disconnect. why does it disconnect. Log message - Status Create Channel Fail 2

Answer (score 1):

The data buffer contains 2byte values and 4byte values. Probably shorts and ints as you can see in the pdf. Do you account for that?

```
0xE7 0x00           APDU CHOICE Type (PrstApdu)  
0x00 0x84           CHOICE.length= 132  
0x00 0x82           OCTET STRING.length = 130  
0x00 0x01           invoke-id (differentiates this message from any other outstanding)  
0x01 0x01           CHOICE (Remote Operation Invoke | Confirmed Event Report)  
0x00 0x7C           CHOICE.length = 124  
0x00 0x00           obj-handle = 0 (MDS object)  
0x00 0x00 0x10 0x15 event-time (set to 0xFFFFFFFF if RelativeTime is not supported)  
0x0D 0x1C           event-type = MDC_NOTI_CONFIG
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its really appreciated. Yes I account for the the shorts and ints. On page 39 of the PDF it shows "Get response with all MDS attributes" I believe this is the hex code I've given above. On page 40 it describes a measurement data transmission that as the blood pressure reading. It says "The agent sends a spontaneous event report to the manager with measurement observations". The problem is the agent sends a disassociation request before it can send measurement observations.

Comment: You write `int number_of_data_packets = data[25];` where you forget data[24]. Why? In the pdf is `config-obj-list.count` that you rename to `number_of_data_packets` which make the code hard to follow. Is ` int sys = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+9]);` really a byte? In the doc there are no bytes. Only shorts and integers. So what happens there? What is the problem with an agent sending a disassociation request before it sends a measurement ?

Answer (score 1):

@ Jieqin - great that you got it too :)

paste this in your reading thread under the block of

```
else if (data[0] == (byte)0xE7){
Log.i(TAG, "E7");
//work for legacy device...
if (data[18] == (byte) 0x0d && data[19] == (byte) 0x1d)  //fixed report
```

to parse your agents answer - and if it works, please rate my hints :)

```
else if (data[18] == (byte) 0x0d && data[19] == (byte) 0x1f)  //mp var report
                        {
                                count = 999; 
                                //set invoke id so get correct response
                                invoke = new byte[] { data[6], data[7] };
                                //write back response
                                (new WriteThread(mFd)).start();     
                                //parse data!!
                                int length = data[21];
                                Log.i(TAG, "length is " + length);
                                // check data-req-id 
                                int report_no = data[25];
                                int number_of_data_packets = data[29];
                                //packet_start starts from handle 0 byte
                                int packet_start = 36;
                                final int SYS_DIA_MAP_DATA = 1;
                                final int PULSE_DATA = 2;
                                final int STATUS = 3;
                                for (int i = 0; i < number_of_data_packets; i++)
                                {
                                    int obj_handle = data[packet_start+1];
                                    switch (obj_handle)
                                    {
                                    case SYS_DIA_MAP_DATA:
                                        int sys = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+9]);
                                        int dia = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+11]);
                                        int map = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+13]);

                                        Log.i(TAG, "sys is "+ sys);
                                        sendMessage(RECEIVED_SYS, sys);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "dia is "+ dia);
                                        sendMessage(RECEIVED_DIA, dia);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "map is "+ map);

                                        break;
                                    case PULSE_DATA:
                                        //parse
                                        int pulse = byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+5]);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "pulse is " + pulse);
                                        sendMessage(RECEIVED_PUL, pulse);
                                        break;
                                    case STATUS:
                                        //need more signal
                                        Log.i(TAG, "STATUS");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    packet_start += byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+3]) + 4;   //4 = ignore beginning four bytes
                                }                               
                        }
```

Comment: This works, i've already done this. What i'm trying to do is to grab data from OMRON's memory. If i send right after taking a reading, i'll get the data alright. However, if i try to send from memory, i will get an E4. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

afaik you have to choose between automatic or push upload.

if automatic is working and you can read the data, then just disable auto upload and push the data via the upload button to your device directly after a measurenment...

regards

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your answer. However, one of the issues I had was that you need to take a new blood pressure reading every time you want to upload data. Otherwise it doesn't send a blood pressure reading.

Comment: exactly, either you do it manuel by pushing upload after a measurenment or you do it automaticly...
but once it is send, you have to measure once again...

Answer (score 0):

you maybe should send the right device address in the data_AR back to the device - in your case: 002209225835c328

therefor you should exchange:

```
(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08,  //bt add for phone, can be automate in the future

(byte) 0x3C, (byte) 0x5A, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0xFF, 

(byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0xE3,
```

with:

```
(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08,  //bt add for phone, can be automate in the future

(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x22, 

(byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x28,
```

and also use the 
`0x00 0x03 result = accepted-unknown-config` like

```
final byte data_AR[] = new byte[] {         
             (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x00,
             (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x2C, 
             (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03,
```

**EDIT:**

I made an Error - the Address is not the one of your BPM-DEvice but of your Phone...
To get a EUI 64-Bit Address out of your 48bit MAC Address, just split it in the middle and add 0xFF 0xFE like:
`BT 48bit MAC [00:11:22:33:44:55]` becomes

```
EUI 64 Bit [00:11:22:FF:FE:33:44:55]
```

I am very sorry

Comment: I'm also doing a similar project, using the same IEEE_10407_10407 protocol. I've changed my device id to the id i acquired in E2.2.2, and also set the result = accepted-unknown-config to 0x00 0x03, sending E2.2.3. I am able to get E3.2.2 Remote operation invoke event report configuration and not able to get anything else.

Comment: If you got this working and you got a dissassociaton  (E4) please configure your OMRON device to send the data directly after measurenment and you will get your data (watch the event type - i got 0D 1F)

Comment: Thanks! I got the data. FINALLY! But if I want to send data that is already stored in memory, what do I need to do?

Comment: see the new answer for getting the data parsed

Comment: Erm... New answer? Where?

Answer (score 0):

I read the IEEE from here: [IEEE 11073-20601-2008](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=05703195)

Please look at page 57 on CLause 7.4.4:

> Agent-initiated measurement data transmission is sent by the agent,
>   for example, as a result of a new measurement that is taken.
>   Manager-initiated measurement data transmission is explicitly
>   requested by the manager by issuing a command (i.e., MDS-Data-Request)
>   to instruct the agent to start or stop sending measurement data.
>   Dependent on the capability of the agent, the time period while this
>   reporting mode is active is configurable (e.g., fixed period or always
>   while associated). A manager shall support receipt of both agent- and
>   manager-initiated measurement data transmission from an agent. An
>   agent may support generation of either one or both agent- and
>   manager-initiated measurement data transmission. In both agent- and
>   manager-initiated measurement data transmission, event reports are
>   used to carry the measurement data.

Comment: when i try to get request with an MDC_ACT_DATA_REQUEST action type a remote operation error (roer) [0x0300] with no-such-action is returned when the action command is illegal no-such-action(9)^, so there is probably no way to get the stored data since it is not supported