# Android Bluetooth HDP-Blood Pressure Monitor

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Hi I have developed an android program to display the readings from an omron bp monitor.  In the IEEE specification of BP monitors it is said that the BP monitor can send upto 25 datas in one event report.
I am getting the following as data from the monitor,it has only one reading and sometimes it is not the latest reading but the first one from the device's memory

```
e7000052005000010101004a0000ffffffff0d1f0040f000000100010038004200030032000100
12000300060062004d005420140327213502000002000a005120140327213502000003000
a000020140327213502000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
```

How should I get the program to get the latest data or how can I send request monitor to send multiple measurements in one event report?Pls help

Comment: anyone has any idea about the data sheet of omron bp monitors?where can i get one?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to consult the data sheet for the device which describes all the data, and how it should be interpreted.

This data string, actually should contain all the data.

The data sheet should have the details about which bits or a combination of bits gives you what.

**For example:**

*The first 3 bits would give you the Device short name*

*The 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th bit would give you the timestamp of the reading.*

*The 9th and 10th bit could give you the Systolic measurement, and so on.*

**IEEE** doesn't specify how this data should be arranged I guess. I have worked on another BP monitor, whose manuals had elaborate documentation about this.

Comment: There is nothng about the data format in the omron device manual.
Atleast I didn't receive any data sheets with my device :(

Comment: In the IEEE document there is a specific data format mentioned.But that is for a single reading.

Comment: I am quite sure that they would have a manual somewhere. Could you mention the device details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591637/parsing-raw-data-received-from-bluetooth-hdp-device Check this question, and see if this helps.

Comment: BP monitor is Omron BP792IT

Comment: I have referred that question.It doesn't help regardng this issue